# How can I find an Adventure or Adventure Path I need that meets certain criteria?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, published-adventures

Let's say I'm looking for an adventure or adventure path. I know I'll have a team of *X* players characters, I want said adventure or path to start at *Y* character level and take them up to *Z* level.

So, is there any way to just get a list of published adventures and paths that meet *X*, *Y* and *Z* requirements, more precise than Google search and faster than just listing them all on publisher page and reading all descriptions?

I also want to include or avoid specific tropes (like "yes/no psionics, yes/no good-only"), but that should be easier. I'll see this as a bonus point for any method, bot it is not crucial.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Using the adventure finder

Paizo has a tool called the [Adventure Finder](https://paizo.com/store/pathfinder/adventures/adventureFinder), which organizes all official and third-party adventures that are available on their site, organizing by level, region or solo games.

You have the starting level, but you cant tell at a glance the end level. Most adventure paths end at levels 16 or 17, while old modules lasted for 2 levels and newer modules last for 3 levels. As most adventures are aimed with a group of 4 to 6 players in mind, that should be the number you are aiming at.

Comment: Geez. How did I fail to find it?!

Comment: If it helps, I didnt know about it until after I had bought over 20 adventure books from paizo.

Comment: Thanks. I feel less bad about myself now. For such obvious tool, it is surprisingly hard to google it and I browsed Paizo page just yesterday, failing to find it.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Adventure Lookup](https://www.adventurelookup.com/adventures/). It covers most major systems and is more like a curated wiki than a catalog. You cannot buy things on it and it lists both old and new adventures.

I love that it has some adventure content filters too based on things like terrain, or included monsters and magic items; which is cool if you have a few specific ideas.